# ruby array of hash with same value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array done in this way

```
[{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"}, {"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]
```

and I have to split into groups with the same value of `"g"`, like

```
[{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}],
[{"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"}],
[{"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}],
[{"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]
```

I tried to `a.map{|a| a['g']}.uniq` to find all the unique `"g"` and then to use `each` function to the resulting array to apply a `select` to the first array, but produce no result. Some one knows how to divide the array in groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input = [{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"}, {"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]

grouped = input.group_by { |hash| hash["g"] }
# => {
#      1=>[{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}],
#      2=>[{"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"}],
#      3=>[{"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}],
#      4=>[{"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]
#    }
```

Then to get your solution you call `grouped.values`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @Max's use of `group_by`, but wish to show an alternative that should be similar in efficiency. Both produce a hash and then extract its values.

```
arr = [{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"},
       {"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |f,h| (h[f["g"]] ||= []) << f }.values
   #=> [[{"g"=>1, "f"=>"01"}],
   #    [{"g"=>2, "f"=>"02"}, {"g"=>2, "f"=>"03"}],
   #    [{"g"=>3, "f"=>"04"}], 
   #    [{"g"=>4, "f"=>"05"}, {"g"=>4, "f"=>"06"}]]
```